# i get toLowerCase error when i use setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would be grateful if you could guide me. i don't know why do i get this error when i use setTimeout. i use no where this function toLowerCase
my Code:

```
$('#name').keyup(function () {
    let $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        let res = Validation.unique($(this).val());
        switch (res.status) {
            case 422:
                let content = '';
                if (!$this.hasClass())
                    $this.addClass('is-invalid');
                $.each(res.responseJSON.errors, function (key, value) {
                    content += value + '<br>';
                });
                $this.siblings('p').html(content);
                break;
            case 1:
                if ($this.hasClass())
                    $this.removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
                $this.siblings('p').html('');
                break;
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

and this is error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at jQuery.fn.init.val (admin.app.js:14656)
at <anonymous>:88:49
```

Comment: What is ```Validation``` ?

Comment: It is a typo caused by this line :`let res = Validation.unique($(this).val());` it should be `let res = Validation.unique($this.val())`

Comment: Validation is just a custom class. that error is not for that i checked that. @Anup